# How do I set up Debugging?

Tags: errors, wp-config, debug, wp-debug

In my wp-config.php, I have:

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

However, the debug.log file is empty. It wasn't being created so I created it and then set its permissions to 666, yet it remains empty. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788660/with-wp-debug-log-set-to-true-no-debug-output-shows-in-debug-log-why

Comment: Do you see errors if you don't disable display?

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin for this issue. Even if debug is set to false, it still prints error to the screen in red.

It is easy and fast to create the plugin.

- In your plugins folder in your wordpress install, create a new file and call it anything you like, for instance, debugger-plugin.php.
- Open up your newly created file, and paste the following code in there and save it. (this code comes from [this post](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/display-php-errors-as-wordpress-admin-alerts--wp-23993) on code.tutsplus.com/

  ```
  <?php
  /*
  Plugin Name: Debugger Plugin
  */
  function admin_alert_errors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){

      $errorType = array (
           E_ERROR                            => 'ERROR',
           E_CORE_ERROR           => 'CORE ERROR',
           E_COMPILE_ERROR        => 'COMPILE ERROR',
           E_USER_ERROR           => 'USER ERROR',
           E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  => 'RECOVERABLE ERROR',
           E_WARNING              => 'WARNING',
           E_CORE_WARNING         => 'CORE WARNING',
           E_COMPILE_WARNING      => 'COMPILE WARNING',
           E_USER_WARNING         => 'USER WARNING',
           E_NOTICE               => 'NOTICE',
           E_USER_NOTICE          => 'USER NOTICE',
           E_DEPRECATED                   => 'DEPRECATED',
           E_USER_DEPRECATED      => 'USER_DEPRECATED',
           E_PARSE                => 'PARSING ERROR'
      );

      if (array_key_exists($errno, $errorType)) {
          $errname = $errorType[$errno];
      } else {
          $errname = 'UNKNOWN ERROR';
      }
  ob_start();?>
  <div class="error">
    <p>
      <strong><?php echo $errname; ?> Error: [<?php echo $errno; ?>] </strong><?php echo $errstr; ?><strong> <?php echo $errfile; ?></strong> on line <strong><?php echo $errline; ?></strong>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <?php
  echo ob_get_clean();
  }

  set_error_handler("admin_alert_errors", E_ERROR ^ E_CORE_ERROR ^ E_COMPILE_ERROR ^ E_USER_ERROR ^ E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR ^  E_WARNING ^  E_CORE_WARNING ^ E_COMPILE_WARNING ^ E_USER_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^  E_USER_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED    ^  E_USER_DEPRECATED    ^  E_PARSE );
  ```
- You can now activate your debugger plugin from the back-end whenever you want. No need to make changes to wp-config.php :-)

Comment: I'm on a live site, so I need to send php error reports a log of some sort. Also, I added and activated this plugin but it did not show php errors on the page.