# Page doesn't load

Tags: plugins, php, array

I have following code, but my page doesn't load anymore. What is wrong?

```
require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'menu.php');
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'getuser.php');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ffd_load_scripts' );

function ffd_load_scripts()
{
    $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
    $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );  

    $arguments = array();
    for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
    {
        $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
    }

    wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', merge_array(array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo']),$arguments)
        );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('ffd_js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ffd_js_script.js');
}
```

Previously it worked fine, the problem is given by the $arguments I think. Tried some things but still have this issue.

The problem is located in this part:

```
$arguments = array();
    for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
    {
        $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
    }

    wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', merge_array(array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo']),$arguments)
        );
```

When I use this code, everything works fine, but I really need the iterator:

```
function ffd_load_scripts()
{
    $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
    $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );  

    /*$arguments = array();
    for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue['fieldcount']; $i++)
    {
        $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
    }*/

    wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo'],
            'index1' => $myoptionValue['id1'],
            'index2' => $myoptionValue['id2']
            )
        );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('ffd_js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ffd_js_script.js');
}
```

Comment: It's `array_merge()`, not `merge_array()`. You should consider using [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) while testing.

Comment: Omg, stupid mistake! Will test tomorrow, debug is enabled but i didnt receive any errors on firebug. Is there a document anywhere with proper debug advise?

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;-) There's a link in my comment and you can also check [this one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: Create yourself a debugging plugin. Check out [my answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158867/31545). I use it successfully

Comment: Array_merge did the trick! Pieter thanks for that, I will definitely use it.